# Fixed position div with width 100% causes body to overflow horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have a weird bug on my website which I've never seen before. The link to the live demo is [website](http://igsdemo.ml)

On Mobile view, body and html is overflown and I can scroll the whole body to left and right. After inspecting, I know that the culprit is **Navigationbar-toolbar**. Somehow it has the extra position right -6px which I don't understand. Anybody knows how to fix this issue? I've tried setting overflow: hidden to ,  but none is working.

In the screenshot below, notice that there is a scrollbar at the bottom of the webpage.

[image]

I will provide further SCSS code if required.

Comment: Actually the problem lies somewhere in your "Main"-Slider. It's pretty obvious that the Navigation has nothing to do with it when you remove the HTML in Chrome or Firefox dev tools.

Comment: @Schwierig you're right, the real culprit is the sliders

Comment: @YaphatS I tried in google chrome mobile view and I am not able to scroll it either left or right. Give me some clue.

Comment: @Bhansa I've already solved it with Schwierig suggestion , I will now updated my question with a screenshot.

Comment: Oh! okay got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @Schwierig said, the real culprit is the slider, for desktop view, I want the slider's items to be fitted to the left and right edges so I added this class to the slider:

```
.Slider--fitEdges {
    // Fix edge
    .slick-slide {
      margin: 0 18px;
    }

    .slick-list {
      margin: 0 -18px;
    }
  }
```

Now I just have to wrap it inside a media query for it to work in desktop only.